# .htaccess cannot catch GET parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^apply/import?$ index.php?action=import [NC]
RewriteRule ^apply/import/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?action=import&code=$1 [NC]
```

I run the following url's and print_r($_GET)

```
"localhost/apply/import" //Prints Array ( [action] => import ) as expected

"localhost/apply/import?code=abc123" // Prints Array ( [action] => import ) only, and is missing code.
```

How do I catch get variable code?

Comment: you've got a slash after import on the second line of your htaccess..

Comment: @scrowler deleted slash and even tried replacing it with a question mark?. In either cases, it still fails. The first htaccess rule still executes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `"localhost/apply/import?code=abc123"`, the first rule is matched (you can check it by removing second rewrite code)
If you want to trigger second rewrite rule, you should try something like `localhost/apply/import/abc123` and this will be the result:

Array ( [action] => import [code] => abc123)

**UPDATE**: I think this can solve your problem:
You can use `[QSA]` to get extra Query String parameters, in your first rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^apply/import?$ index.php?action=import [QSA]
```

Then going to `localhost/apply/import?code=abc123` will output this:
Array ( [action] => import [code] => abc123)

You can read more about [RewiteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). Here is the explanation:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

Comment: Exactly, it's not even reaching the second rule. I have no control over the url with the code param. So far my only work around is to abandon htaccess rules for this particular scenario, but that isn't ideal.

Comment: In second rule, you obviously state that you are looking for some pattern like this: `localhost/apply/import/somecode` so you can't expect that something other than this matches. However, I think I found out what you want, and I updated my answer.

Comment: I saw this solution previously, but wasn't clear how to implement. Thank you. +1

Comment: You're welcome. I've polished my answer a little more, and added some explanations. Check it out.